# How to get a param from URL

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-8

Laravel 8

Hello!
I have some form like this

```
<form id="perpage" action="{{ route('partners.index.perpage') }}" method="get">

<label for="rows">Rows per page</label>

<select name="rows" id="rows" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

Then the form is submited the URL gets string like this:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/partners/perpage?rows=25

127.0.0.1:8000/partners/perpage?rows=50



Route::get('partners/perpage/{rows}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartnerController@indexPerpage')
    ->name('partners.index.perpage');

public function indexPerpage($rows)
{
    ddd('Hello');

    $total = User::find(Auth::id())->partners()->count();
    $partners = User::find(Auth::id())->partners()->simplePaginate($rows);
}
```

This function don`t calling in this case.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include the `rows` in the `route`. There is a ways to do that, first you should remove the `{rows}` from the route:

```
Route::get('partners/perpage', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartnerController@indexPerpage')
    ->name('partners.index.perpage');
```

Then change the `indexPerpage` method:

```
public function indexPerpage()
{
    $rows = request('rows');

    $total = User::find(Auth::id())->partners()->count();
    $partners = User::find(Auth::id())->partners()->simplePaginate($rows);
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the complete route file to your question. I think there is a similar route than can cause this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry! All this time I had a problem with the route cache. Everything is working now! Thanks again!